# Azure VM Resize fails due to limit vcpu

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I was trying to resize a VM from f4s_v2 to DS1_v2. the operation fails with a message because the limit of the vcpus is reached which makes sense.
The details are showing that I have "32" vcpus instead of 10 allowed. I dont know how is this even possible. one solution is to request a limit increase. But, would really appreciate if someone could give an explanation.

Please also check the following message.

```
Insufficient quota
4 vCPUs are needed for this configuration, but only -18 vCPUs (of 10) remain for the Standard FSv2 Family vCPUs.
```

Comment: I tried to repro the issue and everything worked fine for me , didn't face the problem you are having. If the problem still is not resolved please create an support request from azure portal (support+request) for technical assistance .

Answer (score 0):

This is issues seems to be temporary issue. Sometime retrying to might succeeded. If not, please create a Support cases as suggested by [RahulKumarShaw-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969334/rahulkumarshaw-mt) as this requires additional troubleshooting from Azure technical teams.
Create an support request from azure portal (support+request) for technical assistance
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/